# Optimizing inserting the data into access database code

Tags: c#

I am trying to insert data from sql table to access database using C#. The inserting in the access database is taking too much time. It runs for almost 1 hour. Can anyone suggest any way to optimize the code:

Below is my code to insert data into Access database

```
 using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("AccessConnection")))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO RecsCD(RecordingDate, Gr,Grant,DocType,  DocNumber,UserDocNumber,NumOfPages) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    foreach (var records in recList)
                    {

                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecordingDate", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = records.RecordingDate == null ? "" : records.RecordingDate;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("GR", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = records.Grantor == null ? "": records.Gr;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("Grant", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = records.Grantee == null? "": records.Grant;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("DocType", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = records.DocType == null ? "" : records.DocType; ;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("DocNumber", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = records.DocNumber == null ? "" : records.DocNumber; ;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("UserDocNumber", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = records.InternalDocNumber == null ? "" : records.InternalDocNumber; ;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("NumOfPages", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = records.NumberPages == null ? "" : records.NumberPages; ;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
```

The query that I am using to insert the data is just a select query:

alter procedure RecLoad_GetPrimeparsedData

AS

```
 SELECT 
       [RecLoadId]
      ,[DocNumber]
      ,[InternalDocNumber]
      ,[RecordingDate]
      ,[DocType]
      ,[DocDescription]
      ,[Gr]
      ,[Grant]
      ,[NumberPages]
      ,[SourceCode]
      ,[Parcel_No]
  FROM [db_recload].[dbo].[RecLoadSplit]
```

I am getting the data in C# using a stored procedure:

public List getPrimeData()
    {

```
    return _context.RecLoad
         .FromSql("EXECUTE RecLoad_GetPrimeparsedData").ToList();

}
```

there are total 6843 rows in the table

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211114/discussion-on-question-by-anjali-optimizing-inserting-the-data-into-access-datab).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to append to the Parameters collection without clearing it.

Try `cmd.Parameters.Clear();` before calling Parameters.Add()

All the overloads in the source code for the Add method of `ParameterCollection` shows that the new parameter is appended to the end of the list. I don't exactly know what kind of overhead having thousands of parameters with the same name brings up, but I know for sure that you should clear the parameters before populating them for a new query.

```
                foreach (var records in recList)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecordingDate", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = records.RecordingDate == null ? "" : records.RecordingDate;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("GR", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = records.Grantor == null ? "": records.Gr;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("Grant", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = records.Grantee == null? "": records.Grant;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("DocType", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = records.DocType == null ? "" : records.DocType; ;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("DocNumber", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = records.DocNumber == null ? "" : records.DocNumber; ;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("UserDocNumber", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = records.InternalDocNumber == null ? "" : records.InternalDocNumber; ;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("NumOfPages", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = records.NumberPages == null ? "" : records.NumberPages; ;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
```

Comment: Thank You. Clearing the parameters made it run in 5 minutes. thats a huge difference in time.

Comment: Thanks, you too stay at home and be safe.Actually, it is taking less than 5 minutes.

Comment: Instead of appending them and clearing every time, you can follow the instructions here (preparing the command parameters once, and setting only their values for each INSERT). This can may be add a few more seconds' gain to your overall execution time: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1256c0c0-f836-4a5c-8772-c3001839d052/bulk-insert-in-ms-access?forum=adodotnetdataproviders